How to install mongodb PHP extension for PHP 7.1 in 2024
I did a clean install of my system and currently running Ubuntu 24.04. I have a legacy project running on PHP 7.1 which uses MongoDB so I need to install the extension for PHP 7.1.
And here comes the problem:

~ sudo apt-get install php7.1-mongodb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.1-mongodb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.1-mongodb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-mongodb'

It exists for all versions from PHP 7.2 to 8.3, but not for 7.1 which I need. Also apt install php-mongodb doesn't help because I have all PHP versions installed from 5.6 to 8.3, so it installs for my default one (PHP 8.3).
Is there any other repo which still has this package? If not, can I somehow manually install it? I have a backup of my disk before clean install so I can get the needed files from there but I need instructions what to copy where.

PHP 7.1 hasn't been supported for almost 5 years. Perhaps now is the time to upgrade your project to PHP 8.3?

At the very least, maybe upgrade to 7.2 as a temporary solution? Shouldn't be too many breaking changes there. But after that really you need to have a project to update your app onto a supported PHP version

I wouldn't be asking that question if this was the option. It's not my project, I'm just an employee and I cannot affect those decisions. Also we do have a much bigger upgrade currently in progress but it will take a while, in the meantime I need to work on support tasks on old project so installing this extension is something I MUST do, there are no alternatives that will help me.

PHP 7.1 end-of-life was December 2019. Maybe you should try to install mongodb-1.6.0 which was released in September 2019: pecl install mongodb-1.6.0.

Thank you, that saved me! So I had to first switch my default PHP version to PHP 7.1, then I executed sudo pecl -d php_suffix=7.1 install mongodb-1.6.0 and at last I've added extension=mongodb.so into files /etc/php/7.1/cli/php.ini and /etc/php/7.1/fpm/php.ini and it seems to be working for now!
